# How to run cron job on hostinger for laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

I need to set some laravel scheduler on hostinger. How to set this ? My commands are located inside app/console/commands/realtime.php file. Should I include this file path in command to run box in hostinger or something else ?

Comment: This article should answer your question: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583465-how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-at-hostinger, what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I don't know what file path to set for laravel. The hostinger documentation most probably is for raw php projects not for laravel. In laravel do I have to create an extra php file or should I give the path to the kernel file inside app/console in laravel ?

Comment: I advice you to be familiar with official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler, everything is described

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up a Cron Job, open Websites → Manage, search for Cron Jobs on the sidebar and click on it:

[image: hostinger cron menu]

Choose type as Php:

[image]

In the field "Command to run", change the path to your project path.

This should be something like:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u1XXXXXXX/artisan schedule:run
```

Select these options to run tasks on every minute:

[image]

And lastly you should schedule the command to run on the `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Console;
 
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Commands\RealTime;
 
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->command(RealTime::class)->daily();
    }
}
```

Instead of using the `daily` schedule you can choose from available methods for different type of schedules, [here is the link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options).

Refer to the task scheduling documentation on [Laravel's official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

There is an article on Hostinger you can refer to:
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583465-how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-at-hostinger

Comment: Added the command to run like "/usr/bin/php /home/u............../domains/quadque.digital/public_html/crmnotification/artisan schedule:run". But when viewing output, the output is empty. What can be the reason ?

Comment: Also my command in kernel.php is like this "$schedule->command('user:notify')->everyMinute()->runInBackground();".

Comment: By the way, I am using laravel 8

Comment: You should not use runInBackground, it is used to push the task to run as a background job.

Only keep $schedule->command('user:notify')->everyMinute()

Comment: worked. Thanks for time and patience,

Answer (score 2):

This command you need to run by going inside **Cronjobs** section inside **Advanced** dropdown

```
/usr/bin/php /home/u2xxxxx/full_domain_path/artisan schedule:run
```